# MongoDb Shutting Down - Missing Index File

Tags: mongodb

2020-06-09T08:01:24.942+0530 I  SHARDING [conn24] Marking collection **.** as collection version: 
2020-06-09T08:01:24.953+0530 I  SHARDING [conn24] Marking collection **.** as collection version: 
2020-06-09T08:01:24.975+0530 I  SHARDING [conn24] Marking collection **.** as collection version: 
2020-06-09T08:01:25.012+0530 I  SHARDING [conn24] Marking collection **.** as collection version: 
2020-06-09T08:01:25.039+0530 I  SHARDING [conn24] Marking collection **.** as collection version: 
2020-06-09T08:01:25.087+0530 I  SHARDING [conn24] Marking collection **.** as collection version: 
2020-06-09T08:01:25.089+0530 I  SHARDING [conn24] Marking collection **.** as collection version: 
2020-06-09T08:01:25.089+0530 I  SHARDING [conn24] Marking collection **.** as collection version: 
2020-06-09T08:01:25.090+0530 I  SHARDING [conn24] Marking collection **.** as collection version: 
2020-06-09T08:01:25.090+0530 I  SHARDING [conn24] Marking collection **.** as collection version: 
2020-06-09T08:01:25.103+0530 I  SHARDING [conn24] Marking collection **.** as collection version: 
2020-06-09T08:01:25.113+0530 I  SHARDING [conn24] Marking collection **.** as collection version: 
2020-06-09T08:01:25.116+0530 I  SHARDING [conn24] Marking collection **.** as collection version: 
2020-06-09T08:01:25.138+0530 I  SHARDING [conn24] Marking collection **.** as collection version: 
2020-06-09T08:01:33.210+0530 I  SHARDING [conn24] Marking collection **.** as collection version: 
2020-06-09T08:01:33.211+0530 I  SHARDING [conn24] Marking collection **.** as collection version: 
2020-06-09T08:01:33.224+0530 E  STORAGE  [conn24] WiredTiger error (2) [1591669893:224119][616:140720331510368], file:index-627--1881656250781130114.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: __win_open_file, 541: *\index-627--1881656250781130114.wt: handle-open: CreateFileW: The system cannot find the file specified.

: No such file or directory Raw: [1591669893:224119][616:140720331510368], file:index-627--1881656250781130114.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: __win_open_file, 541: *\index-627--1881656250781130114.wt: handle-open: CreateFileW: The system cannot find the file specified.

: No such file or directory
2020-06-09T08:01:33.225+0530 E  STORAGE  [conn24] Failed to open a WiredTiger cursor. Reason: UnknownError: 2: No such file or directory, uri: table:index-627--1881656250781130114, config: overwrite=false
2020-06-09T08:01:33.225+0530 E  STORAGE  [conn24] This may be due to data corruption. Please read the documentation for starting MongoDB with --repair here: http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/repair
2020-06-09T08:01:33.225+0530 F  -        [conn24] Fatal Assertion 50882 at src\mongo\db\storage\wiredtiger\wiredtiger_session_cache.cpp 101
2020-06-09T08:01:33.225+0530 F  -        [conn24]

***aborting after fassert() failure

It happens on almost every 10th query made to the database

Looking for help how it could be resolved?

Comment: No. Infact the specified file does not exists in the data directory.

Comment: It is trying to create the file?